# How to create my own plugin composer command

Tags: php, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I have researched on google to find how composer command can create for my cakephp plugin.

I have created my plugin and i want to publish other cakephp plugin so any user can download though composer and can install easily.

Please let me know how this is working, where should i upload my plugin and can create an composer command so anyone can install my plugin.

Please help or suggest me what should i do?

Comment: [Packigist](https://packagist.org/)?

Comment: Do you still look for an answer?

Answer (score 3):

go to https://packagist.org and after login just click on submit for submitting your package. before submitting the package you have to check the package. your package name should be lowercase.